# Is it OK to only use the wordmark of a logo?

Tags: logo, branding, best-practice

I have a logo that resides in this category:

**Combination mark**

> When a symbol and a wordmark fall in love, they make a logo. More specifically, a *combination mark* (a traditional logo) is comprised of a type-based and a graphic-based mark. - [UX Collective - Symbol, emblem, wordmark: A comprehensive guide to logo types](https://uxdesign.cc/symbol-emblem-wordmark-a-comprehensive-guide-to-logo-types-e08c247c7ab)

Is it ok to only use the wordmark without the symbol/icon of the full logo(icon/symbol + wordmark)?

If yes, can you provide some examples of brands that have done that?

Comment: Since you're using an existing logo, you should refer to its branding guide. Typically this will include if you can use the wordmark separately.

Comment: I don't know if I have enough knowledge to write an answer but I just made a graphic this morning for Capella University where they asked me to separate the symbol from the Word Mark to use in 2 different graphics. I agree with the above comment, I imagine the brand guidelines would let you know if you can do this.

Comment: Depends on who might object. . .  Who owns the logo? Who made it - you or someone else? Are there brand guidelines to follow? Did your client ask you to modify it? etc, etc. There are too many unknowns here to give you a yes or no.

Comment: My Client is going through a transformation of his brand.. the logo was created by someone else and there are very few brand guidelines. In this case I will consult with the person that created the logo.

Still I wanted to generally know if this has been done before.